# Fetch all images local identifier/file path without loading PHAsset us Photos Library

Tags: ios, iphone, photosframework

Can we fetch only the asset local identifier/file path without loading all the PhAsset and individually taking its local identifier/file path? Currently we get this by fetching all assets and then taking each of the assets url.Any better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can. PHAsset.h only contains methods that allow you to fetch the entire asset. You can filter which assets you fetch, but not individual components of the asset.